# Implementing Azure AD (Microsoft.Identity.Web) ontop of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore (Local Users)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

My Web Application (.NET 6) was originally built using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore to handle user accounts locally. Now I need to add support for Microsoft Azure AD. Through researching I found the Microsoft.Identity.Web library which appears to make implementing Azure AD *extremely* simple, and I was able to get a basic implementation working rather quickly, however I ran into issues as soon as I began working on the "post-redirect" tasks.

These Steps *WORK* correctly

- User Browses to site
- User Clicks "Login with Work Account"
- User is Redirected to Microsoft
- User Logs in
- User is Redirected back to my Application

The problem starts at this point, when my controller method is hit, everything is null as if there is no user account information, no claims nothing. It almost appears as if the user just clicked the refresh button.

For testing purposes, I created the following method in the AccountsController to handle the user redirect

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> HandleLoginRedirect(string token = null)
{
    var userAccount = User.Identity;
    var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

    //You get the user's first and last name below:
    var name = userClaims?.FindFirst("name")?.Value;

    return View("SelectBuilding");
}
```

When the user is redirected they hit this function correctly, however token, userAccount and userClaims are all null. So I am unsure how I am supposed to lookup the users local account and/or create a local account for them if they don't have one? Shouldn't I be able to see atleast the users Name and/or Email address?

I did find that I can add an Event Handler "OnTokenValidated" that appears to be fired before the AccountController method is fired, and inside that event handler I can see several pieces of information including the user name & email address.

Here is an example of the OnTokenValidated event, in this event the tenantId is correctly set, and if I inspect context.SecurityToken.Claims I can see ~15 claims for the user account.

```
azure.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
{
   string tenantId = context.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "tid" || x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")?.Value;

   Console.WriteLine("Token Validated");
};
```

Comment: Where does variable User come from?  IActionResult is the deserialize body of the request/response.  Does your code get any data back from the database?  Verify the query to the database gets back data.